# How do I get the value of a latin1 cookie in django?

Tags: django, cookies, character-encoding, wsgi

I need to get the value of a cookie that is encoded in latin1; just using `request.COOKIES['cookiename']` is truncating it at the first hibit character (presumably because it isn't valid utf8 from that point).

I'm running django under mod_wsgi; the cookie is set by a different server that isn't running python and can't easily be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the raw cookie header with `request.META["HTTP_COOKIE"]`, then parse it with the [`Cookie`](http://docs.python.org/library/cookie.html) library.

For example:

```
>>> import Cookie
>>> x = Cookie.SmartCookie()
>>> x.load(request.META["HTTP_COOKIE"])
>>> x['spam']
<Morsel: foo='eggs'>
```

Comment: per http://docs.python.org/library/cookie.html#Cookie.SerialCookie there seem to be security concerns with SmartCookie?

Comment: in any case, this also truncates the data at the first hibit character